# Which is more performant array.includes or string.includes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, performance

I am trying to find out which is more performant:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4]
array.includes(4)
```

or

```
let str = "1234";
str.includes(4);
```

and have tried to find it out by executing:

```
console.time();
let ar = [1,2,3,4,5];
ar.includes(4);
console.timeEnd();

console.time();
let str = "12345";
str.includes("4");
console.timeEnd();
```

in the console and from a script within the page. When directly executing from the console, the times are such that array.includes takes the least time. When executing from a page, the times reported are such that string.includes takes less time. What gives?!

Comment: Is it yours test on jsperf.com? Even I noticed the same thing now! String.includes is fast on chrome's console vs on jsperf

Comment: Yes I just created the test on jsperf at https://jsperf.com/array-includes-vs-string-includes

Comment: Recreated the same using benchmarkJS, the library. Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/533hc71h/464/

Comment: Note only four elements isn't a good benchmark for testing here. As `array.includes` may have a slight initial constant overhead compared to `string.includes` along with other outside factors. Increase this to each 50+ elements and you will get the results you would expect in both cases.

Comment: Chrome 58.0.3029 / Windows 10 0.0.0 -- jsPerf -- `Array.includes` is much faster. `String.includes` comes out 81% slower.

Comment: jsperf -- arr.includes(4) - 6,925,771 ±12.42% 83% slower *and* str.includes("4") - 36,381,922 ±0.72% fastest : Safari 10.1.1 / Mac OS X 10.12.5

Comment: jsperf -- Chrome 58.0.3029 / Mac OS X 10.12.5 -- arr.includes(4) - 49,036,219 ±0.80% fastest *and* str.includes("4") - 15,905,764 ±0.85% 68% slower

Comment: There are a few things to do to make a proper microbenchmark (don’t just time one run, for example), but even then, microbenchmarks can only go so far (especially with modern JavaScript runtimes and their complex optimizations). Do a real-world test if it matters (which I can’t imagine it does in this case).

Comment: @shashankan I think the difference in your case is the declaration part included in the time calculation. Move it out, you should see consistent results. Checkout the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**With small number of values to test against**:

- On Benchmark Suite: https://jsfiddle.net/533hc71h/464/
- On Node: [image: String includes vs Array includes]
- On Chrome console: [image: Chrome1]

Conclusion: `array.includes` is faster than `string.includes`

**Then I tried increasing the number of values to ~100**:

- On Benchmark Suite: https://jsfiddle.net/533hc71h/465/
- Node[image: Big Comparison]
- Chrome console: [image: Chrome comparison]

Ended up with same results: `array.includes` is faster than `string.includes`

---

If you are interested in the implementation algorithm you can look at it here:

- Array includes: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.includes
- String includes: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.includes

---

PS: In your case, I think the variable declaration is taking more time in Array Incldues test than string declaration. If you move the declaration out of the timer, you should also see consistent results.

Proof: [image: Proof]

String declaration takes 1/10th the time that it takes to declare an array

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes` takes the value, loops through the array and try to match the looped value with the search value whereas on the other hand `String.prototype.includes` needs to not only loop through the string (string = array of chars), but it needs to compare more than one value. Let's say you go for `string.includes("Foo");` on string `abcFoo`. It searches for the `F`, then try to compare next index after `F` with `o` and then another index after that with other chars you specified. It probably work like that, but It's just my personal thought - nothing proven.

Comment: I removed that part of the answer which had opinions, I don't opinions constitute an answer to the question. The rest of the answer should suffice the OP's question

Answer (score 3):

Based on the benchmark tests on different browser platforms it all depends on the Javascript Engine and runtime elements on that platforms **(Windows, Mac or Ubuntu)**

Chrome on Mac OS yielded `Array.includes` faster than `String.includes` well on Safari Mac OS it was opposite.(jsperf.com testcase created by **@shashanka n**)

and Node v8.0.0 on Mac OS `string.includes` appear's faster than `Array.includes` with result as below

[image]

**Node test case source code:**

```
let ar = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.time("Array");
ar.includes(4);
console.timeEnd("Array");

let str = "1,2,3,4,5";
console.time("String");
str.includes("4");
console.timeEnd("String");
```

**The above testcase on Chrome** [image]

Sometimes test case ambiguity might cause different results. There's no definite method to pin the API's performance, all we can we can spare some milliseconds and live with that until it really matters or hampers the performance on larger-scale.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is relevant because it runs only once. Maybe you could make it run 1000 times to get an average, because I noticed a great variability running test once instead of plenty times :)

Answer (score 1):

I tested with strings instead of number because one important element is **the number / string conversion** in the process.

[image: array.includes vs string.includes comparison]

Array is still much faster...

Here are my 2 test case

```
var ar = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'];
var str = "abcde";
```

[jsFiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/ahywLvpg/)